# Erro acesso remoto banco de dados Firebird 3.0.3

Tags: firebird

Tentando conectar o banco no servidor CentOS7 com o Ibexpert tenho a mensagem:

Unsuccessful execution caused by a system error that precludes successful execution of subsequent statements.
Install incomplete, please read the Compatibility chapter in the release notes for this version.

192.xxx.xxx.xxx/3050:/meudiretorio/dados/meubanco.fdb

tentei com o isql e tambem deu essa mensagem.

pequisei as referencia de outro nos endereços abaixo mas nao consegui nada:

tentei usar as referencia sugeridas no site abaixa mas não deu certo:
https://sourceforge.net/p/firebird/mailman/message/34499944/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você está colocando o plugin win_sspi antes de Legacy_Auth. Isso obriga o uso dele, independentemente do nome de usuário / senha ser digitado.

Tente: `isql "Ip_do_servidor/3050:/var/lib/Firebird/3.0/banco de 
dados.fdb" -user SYSDBA -pass PasswordSYSDBA`

Comment: Deu certo, obrigado...

Comment: Então marca a resposta como correta.